# In expression engine 2 how is content exported for translation?

Tags: content, translation

I have some old EE2 sites and would like to figure out a good way to translate their content. Is it possible to export the content from the database so that it can be translated using a separate tool, then reimported?

Thanks,

Alejandro

Comment: Export, change and import is possible by this 2 plugins, Export: https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/smart-export-pro and Import: https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/datagrab

Comment: Thanks, that sounds much cheaper than buying the translation plugin at $999!

Comment: There are two main modules for translating content, https://eeharbor.com/transcribe/ (currently $175) and https://boldminded.com/add-ons/publisher (currently $200).

Comment: Thanks @Bluedreamer the first isn't bad but the second site lacks a cert so I didn't linger, and seems to only support EE4 +

Comment: Both support EE5 and are in active development

Comment: I need it to work on EE2, but thanks

Comment: @alejandro not wise to remain on EE2

Comment: it's all going to a new cms afterwards. may be that the translation step begins before that migration though..  but thanks @AllInOne :)